# why transformer don't take any arguments?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn

I'm begginer in SciKitLearn, and I'm making my first transformer, but when I run it I'm getting error Transformer doesn't take any arguments

```
class DataFrameSelector(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):

    def init(self, attribute_names):
        self.attribute_names = attribute_names

    def fit(self, Х,y=None):
        return self

    def transform(self,Х):
        return np.array(X[self.attribute_names])
```

Comment: `__init__`...?!

Comment: What he *deceze* meant is to use `__init__` instead of `init`

Answer (score 1):

You should write `__init__` instead of `init`.